# Need help! How to solve this exception

Tags: java, numberformatexception

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

this is how my Java code looks like:

```
int age=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));
```

Comment: You are trying to parse an empty String to an int. That won't work

Comment: [java] tag caretakers: which is the canonical one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numberformatexception+java?sort=frequent&pageSize=50 please close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If request parameter `age` is empty, not a number, or missing altogether, you cannot convert it to a number.

You'll have to decide what to do in such situation, then do it in the cases mentioned above, i.e.:

- Check the parameter for non-emptiness
- Surround the conversion with `try { ... } catch (NumberFormatException e) { ... }`

Comment: thanks, my previous catch statement was just "catch(Exception)" i just had to make it catch(NumberFormatException) and it worked! thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you "age" parameter is not being passed or is being passed with an empty String.  If this is in a doGet of the servlet, the parameter would be on the URL - i.e., "http://something.tld/servlet/myServlet?age=25&fname=Hello"